# Can we run JUnit5 with JMockit-1.30 version?

Tags: jmockit, eclipse-mars, junit5

It is showing a `NullPointerException` when we use Junit5 with Jmockit1.30, but works fine with Jmockit 1.37(latest version)

This is my code executing `RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)`:

```
public class Junit5WithJmockitTest 
{ 
  Tested private User user; 
  Mocked private Department department; 
  Test void testjunit5WithJmockit37Test()
  { 
    new Expectations() 
    { 
      { 
        department.getDepartmentId(); 
        result = 1; 
        new Department(); 
        result = department; 
      } 
    }; 
    user.getUserId(); 
    AssertionUtils.assertNotNull("", user); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the relevant code here first along with what you have tried so far

Comment: Please include the code into the question with proper formatting, not as a comment.

Comment: I incorporated code from the comment section.